# How to close unmodified tabs when opening a new one?

Tags: ide, phpstorm, editor, webstorm

There is a feature on Sublime and VSCode that consists on: When you open a file in a new tab but you don't modify it, that tab closes when you open a new one. If you don't want that tab to close, then you hit `command+s` so it remains open.

On PhpStorm and WebStorm, when you open a new file even if you don't modify it, it remains open when you open a new file.

Any ideas on how to get that functionality on PhpStorm and WebStorm?

Answer (score 3):

The feature's name is "preview tab"

**Ctrl + Alt + s | Editor | General | Editor Tabs | Enable preview tab**

Answer (score 0):

There is no such feature... Please vote for [IDEA-124569](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-124569) to be notified on any progress with this request.
You can use **View/Quick Definition** (`Alt+space` or `Cmd+Y` in default OSX keymap) to preview the file without opening it in editor.

You can also try playing with editor tabs preferences (**Preferences | Editor | General | Editor Tabs**), enable **Close non-modified files first**, for example.